# Change name of file created by migration

Tags: python, alembic

Its possible to change a name o file create by migration? like this `18b6422c9d3f i prefer organize usign date-time like 201705121927

its possible change configs of alembic to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to edit `alembic.ini`.

Parameter that you looking for is `file_template`.

From [docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=file_template#editing-the-ini-file):

> `file_template` - this is the naming scheme used to generate new migration files. The value present is the default, so is commented out. Tokens available 
>   include:
>
> - `%%(rev)s` - revision id
> - `%%(slug)s` - a truncated string derived from the revision message
> - `%%(year)d, %%(month).2d, %%(day).2d, %%(hour).2d, %%(minute).2d, %%(second).2d` - components of the create date, by default `datetime.datetime.now()` unless the `timezone` configuration option is also used.

By default it is set to `%%(rev)s_%%(slug)s`.

Comment: Does adding the `file_template` definition automatically updates existing migration files? If not, is there a way to do this?